# How can I improve this nested MySQL query to avoid redundant WHERE statement?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to improve on a nested MySQL query, using the following table structure (omitting a few dozen not relevant to my question):

**tbl_users**:
`ID | email`  (all subscribers to our email list)

**tbl_mailings**:
`ID | mail_title` (each marketing email)

**tbl_sends**:
`ID | user_id | mailing_id` (each user who was sent each mailing)

**tbl_opens**:
`ID | user_id | mailing_id` (each user who opened each mailing)

**tbl_actions**:
`ID | user_id | mailing_id` (each user who took the target action on each mailing)

I inherited this query that I have been using to get the open rate and action rate for each mailing:

```
SELECT subq_opens.numopens/subq_sends.numsends as Open_Rate,
       subq_actions.numactions/subq_sends.numsends as Action_Rate,
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sends.userID) AS numsends
    FROM tbl_sends WHERE mailing_id = 5694) AS subq_sends,

(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT opens.userID) AS numopens
    FROM tbl_opens WHERE mailing_id = 5694) AS subq_opens,

(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT actions.userID) AS numactions
    FROM tbl_actions WHERE mailing_id = 5694) AS subq_actions
```

Not too elegant, but functional, even though I have to change the mailing ID in multiple places every time.
However, now I need to change that WHERE statement to something a great deal more complicated, and I don't want to have to repeat the WHERE statement so many times.

Is there a way I can reformulate this without the redundant `WHERE`?
I have tried various nesting schemes, but can't seem to find a way to get it right. I can't change anything about the table structure; that is set in stone. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reformulating your query:

```
SELECT 
    numopens / numsends AS Open_Rate,
    numactions / numsends AS Action_Rate
FROM
    ( SELECT 
          ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.userID) 
            FROM tbl_sends AS s
            WHERE s.mailing_id = param.mailing_id
          )  
        AS numsends,
          ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o.userID) 
            FROM tbl_opens AS o
            WHERE o.mailing_id = param.mailing_id
          )  
        AS numopens
          ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.userID) 
            FROM tbl_actions AS a 
            WHERE a.mailing_id = param.mailing_id
          )
        AS numactions
      FROM 
          ( SELECT 
                5694     AS mailing_id,
                417      AS another_parameter,
                'funny'  AS one_more_parameter   
          ) AS param  
    ) AS cte ;
```

Comment: This works!  Thank you!  I didn't think of putting the actual mailing ID into a SELECT statement... kept trying to think of a way to do it with WHERE or FROM.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I guess joining the three table would do the trick:

```
SELECT 
sub.opens / sub.sends AS open_rate,
sub.actions / sub.sends AS action_rate
FROM
(
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT tbl_sends.userID) AS sends,
    COUNT(DISTINCT tbl_opens.userID) AS opens,
    COUNT(DISTINCT tbl_actions.userID) AS actions
FROM
    tbl_sends
LEFT JOIN tbl_opens
    ON tbl_sends.mailing_id = tbl_opens.mailing_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_actions
    ON tbl_opens.mailing_id = tbl_actions.mailing_id
WHERE
    tbl_sends.mailing_id = 5694
) AS sub;
```

---

Another easy way to do this would be:

```
SET @my_mailing_id = <some id>;
<your original query using @my_mailing_id in WHERE>
```

However, because MySQL doesn't support arrays/lists in variables, this only works for a single ID.
A workaraound would be:

```
SET @my_mailing_ids = '1,2,3,6'; -- notice the VARCHAR
<your query with this in WHERE clause:>
... WHERE 0 < FIND_IN_SET(mailing_id, @my_mailing_ids) ...
```

This would avoid the `JOIN` limit - but has *really* bad performance.

Comment: Makes sense... but this is what happens when I try that:
`The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay`

Comment: I get that same error if I run just the inner query and take the outer query out entirely.  I get it even if I just try to run sends and opens, leaving actions out.  What could be wrong?  Thanks for your help... and for the formatting help too!

Comment: Here the modified SQL I am trying (this time with my actual names - the ones in my original question were changed for clarity):

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT core_usermailing.user_id) AS num_sent,
       COUNT(DISTINCT core_open.user_id) AS num_opened

FROM core_usermailing
 LEFT JOIN core_open ON core_open.mailing_id = core_usermailing.mailing_id
 
WHERE core_usermailing.mailing_id IN (1524, 1525, 1526, 1527, 1528)`

Advice?  Thanks again!

Comment: @user2276596 This might be happeing because your tables are _very_ large. How much rows do you have in them? Your server could also be misconfigured - use `SELECT @@MAX_JOIN_SIZE;` to determine the maximum join size.You might then want to have an index on the `mailing_id` columns of your tables.

Comment: @user2276596 When you can run slow queries in your environment without harming production, you might want to have MySQL explain your query. Do `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1; EXPLAIN <query>`. The first statement will allow you to do big joins, the latter one will give you an insight into which rows the engine actually accesses.

Comment: Thanks so much @Lukas!  i really appreciate being able to work with you on this. I will try the EXPLAIN technique above. A few points of context:(1) There are hundreds of millions of rows in the core_usermailings table, (2) Any field that ends in '_id' is indexed, (3) I have no control over table structure or server configuration, just read-only access, (4) the tables are from a proprietary CMS that is common in the narrow market of my industry, (5) I am new at my job, and just trying to make someone else's queries a little more readable and easy to modify.  Thanks again for your insights!